# How to change language on the template in django-rosetta

Tags: python, django, translation, django-rosetta

I installed django-rosetta in my project. I created a .po and .mo files.
The template I have a code that shows the text already translated in the django-rosetta (from django docs).
How to create a link that will direct to each of the translated pages?

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    <!-- Current language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} -->
    <p>{% trans "Welcome to our page" %}</p>
    <p>{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}</p>

    {% language 'pl' %}
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <p>{% trans "Some text to translate" %}</p>
    {% endlanguage %}

    {% language 'en' %}
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <p>{% trans "Some text to translate" %}</p>
    {% endlanguage %}

    {% language 'ru' %}
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <p>{% trans "Some text to translate" %}</p>
    {% endlanguage %}
```

Comment: you mean to create links which should show up already translated in the template where EN is active?

Comment: @doniyor yes, exactly.